# This is a doubt regarding special theory of relativity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation, space-travel

If a beam of light is seen from a moving spaceship in same direction as spaceship, we will observe that speed of light hasnt changed as our time has slowed down but what would happen if we see a light moving in opposite direction to that of spaceship?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula).

Answer (score 2):

> If a beam of light is seen from a moving spaceship in same direction as spaceship, we will observe that speed of light hasn't changed...

> but what would happen if we see a light moving in opposite direction to that of spaceship?

The speed of light will not change. It is constant.

Comment: Yeah but how is it possible...... Suppose the aircraft is moving at half the speed of light.... Then if the beam 1 has speed c then how can beam 2 also have same speed????

Comment: @HououinKyouma You are assuming that the speed of the beam relative to the ground is equal to the speed of the *aircraft* relative to the ground plus the speed of the beam relative to the aircraft.  This is not how velocity addition works in special relativity.

Comment: "...how can beam 2 also have same speed?" This is simply a fact of nature, confirmed by scientific testing. It seems counterintuitive, but that is just an unfortunate consequence of our everyday experience not preparing us for this fact. There really is no good "intuitive" explanation. You must accept it as a fact about the natural world.

Comment: @J. Murray can you please explain that in little bit more detail?